# Using NServiceBus with SqlTransport - Can't verify message stored in SQL

Tags: nservicebus, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm walking through the sample on NServiceBus using the SQLTransport where I apparently don't understand the concepts of transport correctly because I'm not seeing the expected behavior following their sample application which can be found here: https://docs.particular.net/samples/sqltransport-sqlpersistence/

I'm having trouble seeing where the sample data message `OrderSubmitted` is being stored.  My assumption is that, since I'm using the SqlTransport, I should be able to see the message stored in a table (Samples.Sql.Sender) that represents the queue of `OrderSubmitted` items.  There is a sender and receiver in the sample and I've disabled the receiver so that I can verify the message is stored in a table (queue) on a SQL Server.  When the sender starts up, I see a `sender.Samples.Sql.Sender` table show up.  I'm assuming this is the queue for messages sent by this endpoint.  When you send a message, however, I don't see a record in the `sender.Samples.Sql.Sender` table (or any table for that matter), but it indicates the OrderSubmitted was published so where did it go?

I essentially have a producer/consumer pattern that I want to implement with NServiceBus.  I have producers that will generate messages on to a persistent queue.  Then I have one or more worker servers that will take items off the queue and process them.  Because I have multiple workers servers all looking at the same queue to perform work, I need to ensure that only one of them can process any given message (I don't need a topic, I just want a simple implementation of a persistent queue where many worker processes can help process items on the queue.  Can NServiceBus be used for this type of use-case.  Seems like it could but I'm struggling a bit with how that type of environment should be configured.  How should this be configured so that it's treated as a queue of work and not a topic where every instance would try and process the same message?

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NServiceBus;
using NServiceBus.Transport.SQLServer;

public static class Program
{
    static Random random;

    public static async Task Main()
    {
        random = new Random();

        Console.Title = "Samples.Sql.Sender";
        var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration("Samples.Sql.Sender");
        endpointConfiguration.SendFailedMessagesTo("error");
        endpointConfiguration.EnableInstallers();

        #region SenderConfiguration

        var connection = @"Data Source=MySqlServer;Initial Catalog=NServiceBus;Integrated Security=True;Max Pool Size=100";
        var transport = endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<SqlServerTransport>();
        transport.ConnectionString(connection);
        transport.DefaultSchema("sender");
        transport.UseSchemaForQueue("error", "dbo");
        transport.UseSchemaForQueue("audit", "dbo");
        transport.NativeDelayedDelivery().DisableTimeoutManagerCompatibility();

        endpointConfiguration.UsePersistence<InMemoryPersistence>();

        var subscriptions = transport.SubscriptionSettings();
        subscriptions.SubscriptionTableName(
            tableName: "Subscriptions", 
            schemaName: "dbo");

        #endregion

        SqlHelper.CreateSchema(connection, "sender");

        var endpointInstance = await Endpoint.Start(endpointConfiguration)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to send a message");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");

        while (true)
        {
            var key = Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine();

            if (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                break;
            }

            var orderSubmitted = new OrderSubmitted
            {
                OrderId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Value = random.Next(100)
            };
            await endpointInstance.Publish(orderSubmitted)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
            Console.WriteLine("Published OrderSubmitted message");
        }
        await endpointInstance.Stop()
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here and maybe it has the details you are looking for? https://docs.particular.net/transports/sql/#how-it-works

Some concepts:

An endpoint has a queue
When you send a message in a broker transport (like SQL, Azure, Rabbit MQ) a message is saved in the target endpoint queue name
Once the target endpoint is running it will read and delete the message from that queue...

Happy to assist more on a call, just email me directly sean.farmar@particular.net